# How to get the information inside the child of firebase with Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

By referring to the image below. If I want to make a module to list out all all the event info like registerEventName, registerEventLocation.... How should call into it? The second row is uuid of created event person id, follow by event id. Thanks in advance. I want display all the information of the event list created by all user.Please tell me if there was any extra information needed.

[image: Image1]

```
package com.example.jmham.eventuser;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.jmham.eventuser.Model.ListInfo;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.example.jmham.eventuser.ViewHolder.MenuViewHolder;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar;
import com.example.jmham.eventuser.Model.User;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class List_Of_Event extends AppCompatActivity {


    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference eventinfo;

    RecyclerView recycle_menu;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    FirebaseStorage storage;
    StorageReference storageRef;
    EditText search_edit_text;
    FloatingActionButton search_item;
    ArrayList<String> fullNameList;
    ArrayList<String> profilePicList;
    ArrayList<String> contectNumber;
    ArrayList<String> EventId;
    ArrayList<String> EventLocation;
    ArrayList<String> EventName;
    ArrayList<String> EventRadiogroup;
    ArrayList<String> EventStartDate;

    //Search functionality
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ListInfo,MenuViewHolder> searchAdapter;
    List<String> suggestList =  new ArrayList<>();
    MaterialSearchBar materialSearchBar;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <ListInfo, MenuViewHolder> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_event);

        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageRef = storage.getReference();

        //search_edit_text = (MaterialSearchBar) findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text);

        search_edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text);

        /*
        *    ArrayList<String> fullNameList;
    ArrayList<String> profilePicList;
    ArrayList<String> contectNumber;
    ArrayList<String> EventId;
    ArrayList<String> EventLocation;
    ArrayList<String> EventName;
    ArrayList<String> EventRadiogroup;
    ArrayList<String> EventStartDate;   * */
        fullNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        profilePicList = new ArrayList<>();
        contectNumber = new ArrayList<>();
        EventId = new ArrayList<>();
        EventLocation = new ArrayList<>();
        EventName = new ArrayList<>();
        EventRadiogroup = new ArrayList<>();
        EventStartDate = new ArrayList<>();
/*
        search_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent search_bar = new Intent(List_Of_Event.this, search_bar.class);
                startActivity(search_bar);
                finish();
            }
        });  */




/*
        search_edit_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              if (!s.toString().isEmpty()){
                  setAdapter(s.toString());
              }
            }
        });
*/




        recycle_menu = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle_menu);
        recycle_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recycle_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        database  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
       // eventinfo = database.getReference("ListOfEvent");
        System.out.println();
        loadMenu();
        eventinfo = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference ref2,ref3,ref4;
        ref2 = eventinfo.child("ListOfEvent");
        ref3 = ref2.child("ListOfEvent").child();
//DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ChatRoom").child(str);
       ref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


               // Result will be holded Here
               for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                   EventName.add(String.valueOf(dsp.getValue())); //add result into array list

             //      Toast.makeText(List_Of_Event.this, EventName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }

           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

           }
       });
        //System.out.println(eventinfo.child("ListOfEvent").child(RegisterEventId).child("profileImageUr").toString());

        //Search

        materialSearchBar = (MaterialSearchBar)findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
        materialSearchBar.setHint("Enter your Event");
        //materialSearchBar.setSpeechMode(false); No need, becuz we already define it at XML

        // loadSuggest();  //Write function to load Sugggest from Firebase
        // setAdapter();
        materialSearchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggestList);

        materialSearchBar.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // When user type theri text, we wil change list
                List<String> suggest = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String search:suggest){
                    if(search.toLowerCase().contains(materialSearchBar.getText().toLowerCase()))
                        suggest.add(search);
                }
                materialSearchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggest);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        materialSearchBar.setOnSearchActionListener(new MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {
                //When Search Bar is close
                //Restore original adapter

                // if(! enabled) recycle_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {
                // When search finish
                //Show result of search adapter
                //   startSearch(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {

            }
        });

        //  setAdapter(s.toString());
    }
    /*
        private void startSearch(CharSequence text) {
            searchAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ListInfo, MenuViewHolder>(
                    ListInfo.class;
                    R.layout.activity_list_of_event,
            MenuViewHolder.class,ListInfo.("registerEventName")



            ) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(MenuViewHolder viewHolder, ListInfo model, int position) {

                }
            };
        }
    */
    /*  private void loadSuggest(){
          storageRef.orderByChild("registerEventName".equals()).addValueListener(new ValueEventListener()
                                                                {

                                                                }
          );

      } */
    private void loadSuggest(){




        eventinfo.child("ListInfo").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){


            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    ListInfo item = postSnapshot.getValue(ListInfo.class);
                    suggestList.add(item.getRegisterEventName()); // add name of food to suggest list

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void loadMenu(){

        Query query = eventinfo.orderByKey();
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ListInfo> firebaseRecyclerOptions =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ListInfo>()
                        .setQuery(query, ListInfo.class)
                        .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ListInfo, MenuViewHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions) {


            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_list,viewGroup,false);
                return new MenuViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ListInfo model) {
                System.out.println("test ::"+model.getImageToUpload());

                holder.txtRegisterEventStartDate.setText(model.getRegisterEventStartDate());
                holder.txtRegisterEventName.setText(model.getRegisterEventName());
                holder.txtContact_number.setText(model.getRegisterContactNumber());
                holder.txtRegisterEventRadiogroup.setText(model.getRegisterEventRadiogroup());
                holder.txtRegisterEventLocation.setText(model.getRegisterEventLocation());
//               model = storageReference.child("profileImageUrl").child(fileName)
                System.out.println("test ::"+model.getImageToUpload());
                Glide.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImageToUpload()
                ).into(holder.imageView);
                System.out.println(model.getRegisterEventName());
                System.out.println(model.getImageToUpload());
//                String URL = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(model.getRegisterEventId()).child("profileImageUrl");
//                System.out.println("TESTURL: "+URL);

//                Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
//                        .load(URL)
//                        .into(viewHolder.imageView);

                System.out.println(model.getRegisterEventName());
                System.out.println("Highlight" + model.getImageToUpload());

                final ListInfo clickItem = model;
            }


        };
        recycle_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
    }




    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }


//---

}
//search_item
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.

```
databaseRef.child("ListOfEvent").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot userIdSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : userIdSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String regEventName = snapshot.child("registerEventName").getValue().toString();
                    String regEventLoc = snapshot.child("registerEventLocation").getValue().toString();

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: The value of the child of the child (eg. 5555) is not constant, your method might only can call one of the child(child from 5555). I reqiured to call all the variable inside the ListOfEvent and ignore the uid and the id (eg 5555)

Comment: @MANCHUNLIEW updated code. You can use this code to get all List of events now.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
String currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
databaseRef.child("ListOfEvent").child(currentUser).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String key = objSnapshot.getKey();
                    Toast.makeText(Chat.this, key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }
     }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

     }
 });
```

Hope it's help full.

Comment: I want display all event list created by all user

Comment: I mean just display al andl ignore which user create this. This all of the event list

Comment: you want to display only  registerEventName  in list.